# How to inform of exception and continue

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Am writing a library (distributed as a Nuget package), which lets users configure multiple "readers" to a repository. It goes through each reader and access the repository via the first available reader.

Readers have availability status and being unavailable is not an exception. But then, there are some other exception scenarios which the calling application should be informed of. After informing, the program should be able to attempt using the next reader.

These are the options I have considered

- Throw an exception: the problem here is control flow returns
- Accumulate status and return: reader has something else to return, I
  would prefer not to bundle status with it
- Throw exception like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007827): looks scary :) like it might create
  orphan threads or memory leaks
- Eventing: am not sure how to do it via events

Comment: If you just want to collect all exceptions until you're done, you can also just collect them and continue with the next action, and at the end, throw an `AggregateException` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the application should continue, those are not exceptions in the eyes of the caller. Exceptions should always abort.

I would do something like .NET does internally and have an event.

```
public class ReaderFailedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ReaderFailedEventArgs (IReader reader, Exception failure)
    {
    }

    // [.. Two read only properties here ..]
}

public class Worker
{
    public event EventHandler<ReaderFailedEventArgs> ReaderFailed = delegate{};

    public IEnumerable<Data> Process()
    {
        foreach (var reader in _readers)
        {
            try
            {
                return reader.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ReaderFailed(this, new ReaderFailedEventArgs(reader, ex);
            }
        }

        // now, this is a real exception since user expects to get data
        throw new InvalidOperationException("All readers failed");
    }
}
```

Assigning the event with an empty delegate (`delegate{}`) allows us to use the event without having to check if it's empty (it also makes the event thread-safe).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a coordinator that will return results and any exceptions that occurred during processing.

```
public class Coordinator<T> where T: new()
{
    public async Task<Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, AggregateException>> GetResultsAsync()
    {
        var tasks = new Task<T>[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => GetResult(i));
        }

        var results = new List<T>();
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach(var item in tasks)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await item;
                results.Add(result);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }

        return Tuple.Create<IEnumerable<T>, AggregateException>(results, new AggregateException(exceptions));
    }

    private T GetResult(int i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) throw new Exception("Result cannot be even.");
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this can be one way. Is there any way to inform where exception is not part of the signature? like events.

Comment: It can be done any number of way. In the case of events you need to define an event handler that will return the event.