# Java Catch error and continue running to the next

Tags: java

I can't find a way to keep my program running after it catch and error.
For example, I have:

```
String[] num={"1","2","3","NotNumber","4","5"};
```

I want to convert all into Integer, so `num[3]` is invalid, but I want keep running to `num[4]` and `num[5]` after it catch the error.
How can I do so?

Comment: Try this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007633/9068941) of code i believe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you had shown what you had tried so far, but the simplest solution is to wrap your `int.parse()` in a `try/catch` block and swallow the exception.

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    try {
        newItems[i] = Itemger.parseInt(items[i]);
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `try-catch` block inside your iteration

**JAVA 7**

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s : num) {
  try {
    Integer n = Integer.valueOf(s);
    intList.add(n);
  } catch (Exception ex) { continue; }
}
```

**JAVA 8 Streams**

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(num)
  .stream()
  .map(s -> {
    try {
      return Integer.valueOf(s);
    } catch(Exception ex) { return null;}
  })
  .filter(i -> i != null)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```