# if specific exception is caught return to code below the line where it was thrown

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

This is probably stupid but, is it possible to catch a specific exception and then return to where in the function that the exception was thrown a line later?

For example

```
Try
{
//trigger exception 
//return to function here
//more function
}
catch(Exception e)
{
if (e.Message.Contains("exception message contents"))
{Do the return thing}
}
```

Comment: The short answer is no. Can you show us a more meaningful code sample so we can give some advice? And explain why you want to do this?

Comment: You can check this answer:
[Resumable exception c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007608/resuming-execution-of-code-after-exception-is-thrown-and-caught/3007694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stopping you putting a try inside a try..

```
try{
    //some code

    try{ couldGoBoom(); } catch (SomeException) { ... }

    //code you want to "return to"'after the SomeException is done with
} catch(OtherException){
    //etc
}
```